# Send response gradually to frontend when single API call to backend is made

Tags: java, spring-boot, next.js

I need some options for my use case where my backend (spring boot) will keep on receiving data from external source [3rd party APIs](these sources might be at least 4-5) waiting for all might introduce latency.
So to reduce the response time need some mechanism that will quickly send the response as and when I get data from first source to frontend, this will continue till all data is sent.

I am thinking to use websockets (but not sure if that is wise choice)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the frontend doesn't need to send any data back to the server, so if this is the case, You can use Server-Sent Events (SSE). However the performance of SSE is not as good as WebSockets but it can be more efficient than repeatedly polling the server, especially when messages are infrequent.